# Executing script in ajax rendered form with remote in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I render my form after pressing this button

```
= link_to 'New Note', new_note_path, :class => "btn btn-primary new-note-button", :type => "button", :id => "new-link", remote: true
```

by this script in new.js.erb

```
$("#new-link").hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>');
```

it render form that works, but scripts in application.js, that control this form - does not. btw it works, if form generated from load of page, not with js.
there are one of them

```
  $("#noteContent")
          .on("input", function(){
            checkExistNoteContent();
          })
          .ready(function(){
            checkExistNoteContent();
          });
```

Help me please, how to fix this issue ?

rails 4.2.5

DOM

```
 .container.main-section-index
  %h1.text-center Notes
  -if user_signed_in?
    = link_to 'New Note', new_note_path, :class => "btn btn-primary new-note-button", :type => "button", :id => "new-link", remote: true
  -else
    = link_to 'Sign up!', new_user_registration_path, :class => "btn btn-primary sign-up-index", :type => "button"
    = link_to 'Log in!', new_user_session_path, :class => "btn btn-primary log-in-index", :type => "button"
  %hr.head-devide
  //other elements
```

short version of form here:

```
= form_for(@note) do |f|
  .field
    %h5.label-of-content Content
    %br/
    = f.text_area :content, {:class => "form-control content-input", :id => "noteContent"}
    %br/
    .actions
      = f.submit "#{button_label}", {:class => "btn btn-default", :id => "submitNote", :disabled => "disabled"}
```

Comment: You need to use Jquery event delegation, then it will work. Show me the little DOM structure into which you are actually putting the form.

Comment: Added little DOM to head. Thank you for attention, @ArupRakshit

Comment: can you add also your form? or what is the id of the `form` etc?

Comment: so write it like `$(".container")
          .on("input", 'form #noteContent', function(){
            checkExistNoteContent();
          })`..

Comment: added form, will try your solution, thank you, @ArupRakshit

Comment: Arup got it; I'll write an answer but accept Arup's if he posts. He is correct about delegation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delegate your `.on` function:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("input", "#noteContent", function(){
   checkExistNoteContent();
}).ready(function(){
   checkExistNoteContent();
});
```

Whenever you "bind" javascript functions to events on your elements, the elements *have* to be present at DOM load.

If the element is not present at load, JQuery gives you the ability to bind the event to another element, and *delegate* the function to a child element (which *can* be loaded later).

--

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from *descendant elements* that are added to the document at a later time.
>
> By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a `Model-View-Controller` design, for example, or document if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.